# Как нормально подключить Modernizr через Bower?

Tags: gulp, npm, bower

Сколько раз пробовал и так и так, при скачке с бовера в файле библиотеки modernizr.js практически ничего нету, устанавливал плагин gulp-modernizr, но если кто-то подробно объяснить как установить через бовер буду оооочень признателен!

P.S: если подключать через плагин modernizr-min, то тогда библиотека подключется, но при этом при открытии хтмл страницы на долю секунды подгружает страницу и она становится белой, хотя разметка вся присутствует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать плагин main-bower-files. Он вытащит установленные через bower js-файлы в папку проекта, а дальше подключай в html путь к нужному файлу.